# not supported between instances of 'Button' and 'int' tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

im making a *guess number game* but i have a problem:In general, I would like to say how the process of the program is like this: the user first enters the number and clicks the registration option,The second user should try to guess what the number is in a specific number, but my problem is that if I want to create a while loop, it is not possible and it gives an error.

```
>> not supported between instances of 'Button' and 'int' py
```

my codes:

```
from tkinter import *
win = False
sum_1 = 0
def sumbit():
    global asghar
    asghar = int(text.get())
    text.pack_forget()
    sum_1.pack_forget()
    return asghar
def gusses():
    global sum_1
    while sum_1 > 10:
        a = int(text_1.get())
        if a == asghar:
            win = True
            print("you win")
            break
        elif a > asghar:
            print("number is higher")
            sum_1+= 1
        elif a < asghar:
            Label(app,text="number is lower").pack()
            sum_1+=1
app = Tk()
sumbit
app.minsize(300,300)
text = Entry(app,font=20)
text.pack()
text_1 = Entry(app,font=20)
text_1.pack()
sum_1=Button(app,text="player 1 sumbit",font=20,command=sumbit)
sum_1.pack()
Button(app,text="gusses",font=20,command=gusses).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does the traceback tell you what line causes the error?

Comment: line 12, in gusses
while sum_1 > 10:

Comment: Yep. `sum_1` is a `Button` - I think @James_481 has it nailed down.

Answer (score 3):

In the beginning, your code sets `sum_1` to an integer (0). You later make a button and set the same variable to that button. The `gusses()` function expects `sum_1` to be an integer, so the button should probably have a different name.

Answer (score 2):

`sum_1` is an Button object. You are trying to compare it to an integer. This isn't possible. Not sure what you are trying to do here. If you are wanting the text of `sum_1` then you need to do `int(sum_1['text'])`.

Edit: As pointed out by @Thingamabobs `button.text` doesn't work, use `button['text']` instead

Comment: `sum_1.text` isn't going to work. `sum_1['text']` would do. But how should the string `"player 1 sumbit"` be useful in this code ?

Comment: I don't know, but it looks like OP is trying to reference the button some way, I just thought it might be a possibility